# use gdb to map crash stack address to code line

Tags: android, gdb

I have a crash stack from android 11 as below:

```
#01 pc 00025b85  /system_ext/lib/libsn100nfc_nci_jni.so (android::nfaDeviceManagementCallback(unsigned char, tNFA_DM_CBACK_DATA*)+792) (BuildId: 49a45aec53f191b56d0e9b3249ebe94d)
```

And the so has symbols:

```
$ file libsn100nfc_nci_jni.so 
libsn100nfc_nci_jni.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[md5/uuid]=56ba6d380faffef52b19484b178b44b0, with debug_info, not stripped
```

But when load this so to gdb and check the address, I got nothing:

```
$ gdb libsn100nfc_nci_jni.so 

Reading symbols from libsn100nfc_nci_jni.so...
(gdb) info symbol 0x00025b85
xmlSoL + 53 in section .rodata
(gdb) 

info line *0x00025b85
```

Why this address in section .rodata?

BTW, when check address of function:

```
(gdb) info address android::nfaDeviceManagementCallback
Symbol "android::nfaDeviceManagementCallback(unsigned char, tNFA_DM_CBACK_DATA*)" is a function at address 0x2d294.
```

function address at 0x2d294 but call stack crash at 0x00025b85 (greater than function address?)